# Unable to programmatically check Checkbox Column in DGV after editing datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a click event for my DGV which is binded through a datatable. Whenever the checkbox column is checked, it verifies the selected row and presents the condition to the user through a message box. If the user clicks yes, I edit the remarks column in the datatable. My problem is, I need to retain the check mark. It disappears after AcceptChanges();

Here's what I've tried.

```
DialogResult OptScndary = MessageBox.Show("This employee's primary position is not required for the project but the secondary position is. Would you like to request this employee for his/her secondary position?", "Secondary Position", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

if (OptScndary == DialogResult.Yes)
{
     DataRow[] Row = AvailableEmp_dataTable.Select("EmpID='" + Sel_EmpID + "'");
     Row[0]["Remarks"] = "Secondary position requested";
     AvailableEmp_dataTable.AcceptChanges();

     RequestBtn.Enabled = true;

     foreach (DataGridViewRow DGVRow in EmpInfoGrid.Rows)
     {
           if (DGVRow.Cells["EmpID"].Value.ToString().Equals(Sel_EmpID))
           { 
                DGVRow.Cells[MarkColumn.Name].Value = true; 
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Is the check box column bound to the underlying results or not?

Comment: Are you rebinding the DataGridView?

Comment: No I did not rebind the datagridview. It is already bound to the datatable but I applied the changes (in the remarks) to the datatable which it is bound to. Does AcceptChanges(); automatically rebind the datagrid? @Deepak

Comment: What do you mean @KAJ? I don't think it is. I just added the checkboxcolumn for every row in the datatable which the grid is bound to.

Comment: I don't work in windows. So just an imagination, In windows app, if we update the datasource, the control that is bind with that datasource is also gets updated. So I think thats why checkbox in datagridview gets unchecked when you update the datatable.

Comment: I think that if the check box column was part of the data source, the selections would be persisted because when you save changes you'd also save the selections. If its added separately then you need to manage it separately

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection of your checked rows. save the ID's and add a procedure on your DataGridViewRowAdding(not sure about the exact name) event to change the values of the checkboxes based on the collection of checked rows

Comment: You can use Phillip's method. You can use RowAdded Event. Just find the checkbox and if the row id matches with the collection you have saved, just check the checkbox.  Go here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to use the RowAdded event. I am not adding a new row. I'm just editing the remarks of the selected row?

Comment: check what event gets fired after your editing.. so you can do something there

Comment: Sorry it's not the RowAdded Event but RowDataBound.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx
```

The rowdatabound event is fired whenever we rebind the datagridview. So when you check the checkbox, just collect the rows that has checkbox checked. And when user checks a checkbox, let process your logic and then rebind the datagridview and on rowdatabound event, match the row with the stored ids in the collection that you collected during checkbox checked event and if it matches, find the checkbox control in the row and just mark it checked.

Hope this helps.